# Is there a way to move multiple collections under one sub-collection in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I already have data in these collections. I would like to nest all these collections under one collection.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore provides no way to move data.  You have to write code to read existing documents, write them to their new location, and delete the originals.